# Why the animation of a function gives different results from the integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, manipulate, animation, integral-equations

My function is:

```
A1[B_, x_, t_] := (AiryAi[B*(x - (B^3*t^2)/4)])^2
```

(B is a constant) and if I use "Manipulate" :

```
BB1[t_] := Plot[Re[A1[1, x, t]], {x, -20, 22}, PlotRange -> {{-20, 22}, {-0.5, 2}}, AxesOrigin 
-> {0, 0}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Italic], 
Row[{"|", Style["\[Psi]", Italic], "(", Style["x", Italic], ")\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(|\), \ 
(2\)]\)"}]}, AspectRatio -> .25, ImageSize -> {550, 175}]

Manipulate[BB1[t], {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 5, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 
ControlActive[500, 150], MaxRecursion -> 2, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I can see that this function remains unchanged in form. Therefore, the integral of this function from -Infinity to Infinity should be constant for different values of t. However, when I calculate the integral:

```
F1[B_, t_] := Re[NIntegrate[A1[B, x, t], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Method -> 
 "DoubleExponential", WorkingPrecision -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
```

and then try different values for t (B is a constant and it can be equal to 1), it comes out that F1 is not a constant value. Why does this happen?

Comment: You are not integrating the real part of A1, but A1. Try `F1[B_, t_] := NIntegrate[Re[A1[B, x, t]]....`

Comment: Yes you are right! However, the results are still different.

Comment: @ioanna99 With `Module` this simplified code `Module[{}, 
 Manipulate[ {CMax, 
   ProfitRandomization[p, \[Gamma], \[Delta], \[Alpha], 
    CMax]}, {{\[Delta], .317}, 0.01, .9999}, {{\[Alpha], 67.1}, .01, 
   100}, {{p, 2.62}, .01, 10}, {{\[Gamma], 195.706}, 1, 10000}, {CMax,
    0 , 1}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
 ]` works.  Stil don't understand the problems arising with `Plot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this from `Integrate`:

```
Integrate[A1[1, x, 0], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

> ```
> Integrate::idiv: Integral of AiryAi[x]^2 does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}.
> ```

Another check:

```
Integrate[A1[1, x, 0], {x, -A, 0}, Assumptions -> A > 0]
Limit[%, A -> Infinity]

(*  A AiryAi[-A]^2 + AiryAiPrime[-A]^2 - 1/(3^(2/3) Gamma[1/3]^2)  *)
(*  \[Infinity]  *)
```

It seems the integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which problems arise using `Plot`.

Here a workaround:

First add `, MaxIterations -> 1000` in the definition of `ProfitRandomization[..., MaxIterations -> 1000]`

Second enclose your codee with `Module`

Third try

```
Module[{tab}, 
 Manipulate[ 
  tab = Table[{CMax, 
     ProfitRandomization[p, \[Gamma], \[Delta], \[Alpha], 
      CMax]}, {CMax, 0 , 1, .1}];
  ListPlot[tab]
  , {{\[Delta], .317}, 0.01, .9999}, {{\[Alpha], 67.1}, .01, 
   100}, {{p, 2.62}, .01, 10}, {{\[Gamma], 195.706}, 1, 10000} , 
  SynchronousUpdating -> False]]
```

[image]

Code runs quite slow but updates `ListPlot` as expected.

Hope it helps!